# Javascript "this" value is undefined in function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to access variables set at the "window" level (I believe). I am able to reference these in all functions, but when I try to reference it in a event listener function, the values are undefined. In the below code, the `lat` and `lng` values are undefined.

```
<script>
        let map;
        let lat;
        let lng;
        let location_name;
        let travel_radius;
        let circleObject;

        const source = document.getElementById('travel-radius-value');
        function inputHandler(e) {
        console.log('old travel_radius: ' + this.travel_radius);
          this.travel_radius = e.target.value;
          console.log('updated travel_radius: ' + this.travel_radius);
          let lat = this.lat; //<-UNDEFINED
          let lng = this.lng; //<-UNDEFINED
          circleObject.setMap(null);
          circleObject = new google.maps.Circle({
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map,
                center: {lat, lng},
                radius: this.travel_radius*1000,
          });
        }
        source.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);
```

**Update: new code. `lat` and `lng` are still undefined**

```
<script>

        let map;
        let lat;
        let lng;
        let location_name;
        let travel_radius;
        let circleObject;

        const source = document.getElementById('travel-radius-value');
        function inputHandler(e) {
        console.log('old travel_radius: ' + this.travel_radius);
          this.travel_radius = e.target.value;
          console.log('updated travel_radius: ' + this.travel_radius);
          circleObject.setMap(null);
          circleObject = new google.maps.Circle({
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map,
                center: {lat, lng},
                radius: this.travel_radius*1000,
          });
        }
        source.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);
```

Comment: `this` in your code refers to `#travel-radius-value`. Just use the name of the global variable to refer it. If it's shadowed by a local variable, `window.lat/lng/travel_radius` is the way to go.

Comment: @Teemu — No. `window.foo` will not let you access a variable declared with `let`

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, i changed them from `let` to `var` and it's working

Comment: @Quentin, indeed, I've forgotten that, because I've last used global variables a decade ago.

Comment: @Teemu Why? Is it bad practice to use global variables?

Comment: @Tom That's a bit an opinion, but I'd say yes. `window` object is massively crowded, you can't remove globals, they're not garbage collected, they're exposing your data for easy manipulation (not that anything would be safe in JS in a browser), and you usually don't need globals at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [value of `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) is typically the object on which a method is called. In this case it is the element to which the event listener is bound.

Using `this.something` accesses a **property** on whatever object that is.

`lat` and `lng` are **not** properties at all. They are variables. You **cannot** use `this` to access them.

Normally you would **just** use `lat` and `lng` to access them, but in this case you have declared to other variables (inside the function) with the *same names*. This causes the local variables to shadow the ones in the wider scope and makes it impossible to access them.

You therefore **also** need to rename one of the two sets of variables.

Also note that while `this.lat` and `this.lng` are `undefined` (because those properties don’t exist on the element in the first place) the variables `lat` and `lng` (in the wider scope) are *also* `undefined` because you initialise them without assigning values to them.

Comment: i updated my code but the lat and lng are still undefined, even when referencing the variables without the `this` keyword. My updated code is in the quetsion. any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @Tom — I refer you to the last paragraph of this answer.

Comment: @Qutntin, thank you! You helped me figured it out, i changed it from `let` to `var`